# My vm (debian 9.10) is stucked at the booting

Tags: debian, virtualbox

My debian 9.10 launched on a vm is stucked at the booting as shown below[image]

Settings : Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While working on the vm, I disabled the autovt@.service, which produced that error (I had to try that on another installed debian to figure out it). By booting in a recovery mode (as root) I reenabled the service so everything works know. Searching on internet, vt is apparently the virtual terminal which explains why I had no terminal to log in and work...